# aws lambda test with context identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like to test a lambda function that makes use of the context.identity.cognito_identity_id and context.identity.cognito_identity_pool_id in the identity object under the context parameter. The issue is they are null when I run a test through the lambda web interface, and I'm not sure how to set it, I can only set the "event" parameter passed to the function but not the "context". Right now the only way for me to test the lambda function is either locally or deploying the function then updating and deploying the gateway api.

Comment: It's strange that AWS don't offer this functionality.

Comment: according to AWS you interact with AWS Lambda execution environment via the context parameter....
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-context-object.html

Comment: @Rthomas529 that "interaction" is from *inside* the running function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set/pass a context object when testing in the Lambda console, because testing in the console actually invokes the currently selected version (usually `$LATEST`) of the real function in the real Lambda environment.

The console is not a simulator, it's the real thing.  It sends the Lambds service a request to actually invoke the function.

As a consequence, the invocation context is also real and there's no mechanism for spoofing values into it.

You can simplify testing by configuring API Gateway to use the `$LATEST` version of the function.  As soon as you publish a new version of the function, API Gateway should start invoking the new version of the function almost immediately, with no changes or redeployment needed in API Gateway.

Comment: ok I'm going to have to look up how to make it so the gateway api uses $LATEST thank you for the help